# c qsort string array

Tags: c, string, qsort

```
    qsort(words, size1, size2, compareWords);
```

inside compare words:

```
    int compareWords(const void *ac, const void *bc)
```

this works:

```
    char const *a = *(const char **)ac;
```

these don't (`a` gets some garbage values):

```
    char const *a = ac;
    char const *a = (const char *) ac;
```

what is the rationale?

Also, in some examples I see `size2` to be `sizeof(char *)`. Shouldn't this be `sizeof(*words)`?

words is declared as:
`char *words[] = {"abc", "pqr", "abcd", "pqsl"};`

Comment: You must show the declaration of `words`, since you're asking questions about how to access it.

Comment: You're right, `size2` is the size of one element. So, `size2 = sizeof(*words)` or better `size2 = sizeof(char)`.

Comment: @Michael is sizeof(* words) = sizeof(char)?? In my example words array, sizeof(* words) comes out to be 4 whereas sizeof(char) = 1. I don't think they are the same.

Comment: @Sushil, yes my bad... `*words` is a `char*` so yeah `sizeof(char*)` is the same as `sizeof(*words)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `qsort`ing an array of T, your comparison function must convert its `const void*` pointers to `const T*`, because T can't be taken by value.

If `words` is an array of `char*` or `char const *`, you have to convert the arguments to `char* const *` or `char const * const *` respectively, it's natural when said this way.

Comment: hey, thx, but to be precise I wanted to know whats with `*(const char **)ac` - seems pretty un-intuitive to me... what is wrong in typecasting with (const char*)?

Comment: You have an array of `char*`, and the comparison function always receives *pointers to elements in the array*. Therefore, pointers to `char*`. These pointers also happen to be const, so `*(const char **)ac` is not const-correct, though there are no actual consequences since you don't try to write to this pointer.